# Inline mode vs equation* environment

Tags: inline

I want to create

[image]

For this, I write

```
\begin{equation*}  
\sum^* =\sum^0 \cup\sum^1 \cup \sum^2 \cup\ldots  
\end{equation*}
```

But this creates

[image]

Again if I write this in inline mode like

```
$\sum^* =\sum^0 \cup\sum^1 \cup \sum^2 \cup\ldots$
```

then it gives

[image]

Why is this happening? Because I want to write this in `equation*` environment.

Comment: `\sum` is for a summation, so superscripts should go above.  Are you perhaps wanting `\Sigma`?

Comment: Note that, as a cheat, if you really want to use `\sum`, you can type `{\sum}^* ={\sum}^0 \cup {\sum}^1 \cup {\sum}^2` which produces what you're looking for. But the LaTeX police should be here in a minute ;)

Comment: @SebGlav and the punishments? :D

Comment: @ManjoyDas Reading War and Peace typeset in Comic Sans. `:-D`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your typesetting needs correctly, you should be using `\Sigma` rather than `\sum`, and `\dotsb` rather than `\ldots`.

[image]

However, I will readily concede that I may *not* have correctly understood what you're trying to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' env. and '\dotsb' macro
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\Sigma^* =\Sigma^0 \cup \Sigma^1 \cup \Sigma^2 \cup \dotsb
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the difference between `\ldots` and `\dotsb`?

Comment: @ManjoyDas I would recommend reading through the AMS math documentation.  `\ldots` is "lowered dots" (as opposed to "centered").  `\dotsb` is "dots in place of a binary operator".  The default will look like the `\cdots` you want, but this way, a journal could redefine `\dotsb` according to their preference.

Comment: @ManjoyDas - The difference between `\ldots` and `\dotsb` should be evident if you compare (a) the 2nd and 3rd screenshots of your posting and (b) either my code or the 1st screenshot in your posting.